# ASP.NET - Using impersonation but connecting to SQL Server using AppPoolIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, impersonation

We'd like to migrate our SQL Server connections over to using Windows authentication in an ASP.NET application that uses impersonation for connection to a third party system.  If we switch the connection strings to using Windows authentication then the impersonated user gets passed through and the connection fails.

Is there a way to use Windows authentication using the account that the Application Pool is running under, whilst still using impersonation for other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Integrated authentication will use whatever account is currently being impersonated.  Here are a couple things you might try:

1. Limit impersonation scope.  Only impersonate for the method calls which absolutely need it, and stop impersonating immediately after.
2. Use SQL Authentication instead of Windows
3. Impersonate on a separate thread, and access your 3rd party system only via that thread
4. Make your SQL calls through a separate web service which does not use impersonation